# Bring all values in filter except the ones in the condition

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a list of items which I want to filter.
I created a filter that includes a regexmatch with multiple criteria e.g. mo|oa (so it will bring any item that has either `mo` (like `mouse`) or `oa` (`goat`) in the string).
`=filter(A2:A10,regexmatch(A2:A10,C1))`

What I want is to bring the remainder of the list. i.e. all the items that don't fall in the criteria I mentioned (do not include `mo` or `oa`).
I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to get the filter to bring the remainder of the items? If so, how?
2. While trying to figure it out, I used `<>`&C1 (the cell with the condition `mo|oa`).
   `=filter(A2:A10,regexmatch(A2:A10,"<>"&C1))`

Surprisingly, it just disregarded the first part `mo` and showed only result that contain `oa`. I'm curious for the reason.

Here's a demo file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvTN2p2W7Agw9tIfo4ZcsBlujl0Iq0Ft8h9aYuSH4NQ/edit#gid=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT` for `REGEXMATCH`:

```
=filter(A2:A10,NOT(regexmatch(A2:A10,C1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, works like a charm! Any idea about my second question? Why the strange behavior?

Comment: @Tom It is not strange. You ask regex to find strings that contains ```<>mo``` or ```oa``` or ```ar``` so it found ```goat``` and ```leopard```. To make negate you must use something like ```^((?!mo|oa|ar).)*$``` but AFAIK GS regex does not support lookaround.